# Ebean + Play 2.0 Queries

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

When I have:

```
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public String username;
```

public String firstName;
public String lastName;

can I do `User.find.byUsername("myusername")` or `User.find.byFirstNameAndLastName...` or would I have to define the method in the User class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "magic" method in PlayFramework2 *(ok, in reality there is just "less" magic methods)*

So you need to define these functions, or to use a composed statement.

```
User.find.where().eq("username", myUserName).findUnique()
User.find.where().eq("firstname", firstname).eq("lastname", lastname).findList()
```